# Creating a python rock paper scissors game, has a few bugs

Tags: python

```
import random

#Rock Paper Scisscors Lizard Spock Game

#Name to number
rock = ()
paper = ()
scisscors = ()
lizard = ()
Spock = ()

def main():
    print("Let's play rocker, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock")
    computer = npc_guess()
    player = user_guess()
    complete(computer, player)

def user_guess(): #Users hand in RPSLS
    player = input("Choose 'rock', 'paper', 'scisscors', 'lizard', 'Spock'")
    game = True
    while game:
        if player == 'rock' or player == 'paper' or player == 'scisscors'\
        or player == 'lizard' or player == 'Spock':
            return player
    else:
        print("That Choice isn't valid.")
user_guess()

def npc_guess(): #computers hand in RPSLS
    while True:
        computer = random.randrange(0, 4)
        if computer == 0:
            print("The NPC has chosen rock")
            computer == rock
        elif computer == 1:
            print("The NPC has chosen paper")
            computer == paper
        elif computer == 2:
            print("The NPC has chosen scisscors")
            computer == scisscors
        elif computer == 3:
            print("The NPC has chosen lizard")
            computer == lizard
        elif computer == 4:
            print("The NPC has chosen Spock")
            computer = Spock
        return computer
npc_guess()


def complete(player, computer): #determines if the computer beat you, if not you win or tie.
    if computer == ('rock' and player == 'lizard') or ( computer == 'rock' and player == 'paper')\
        or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'scisscors') or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'Spock')\
        or (computer == 'scisscors' and player == 'paper') or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'lizard')\
        or (computer == 'lizard' and player == 'paper') or (computer == 'lizard' and player == 'Spock')\
        or (computer == 'Spock' and player == 'rock') or (computer == 'Spock' and player == 'scisscors'):
            print("The Computer wins")
    elif computer == player:
        print("It was a tie")
    else:
        print("You win!")

main()
```

Couple issues that I can't figure out. Not mattwer what I choose and the NPC chooses, it always says that the user is the winner. It also ask me to choose a choice twice in a row when I run the program.

Comment: You can't just dump your whole code here with two sentences of explanation and expect someone to download it, run it, and polish it for you...

Comment: Remove the function calls you have just after function definitions.

Comment: create a dictionary of with five keys(Computers hand) and the two vals are the losing hands(Player). It'll make your code cleaner

Comment: Also, in your `npc_guess` function you should change all the lines like `computer == compChoice` to `computer = 'compChoice'`. The first is a test for equality with a variable. The second is string assignment.

Comment: @SirParselot OP isn't trying to test for equality in `npc_guess`. OP wants to assign a value to the computer's guess and return it. Currently the value returned would be a random int 0-4, because nothing else is being assigned to `computer`

Comment: @rfj001 you're right, I looked at the wrong function

Answer (score -1):

Ran this, and it seems to be working. See the inline comments for explanations on what wasn't working before and how the changes fix the problems.

Also note that there are still some things to polish up in this code, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

```
import random

#Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock Game

def main():
    print("Let's play rocker, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock")
    player = user_guess() # Switch order of player and computer so player cannot see computer guess before choosing
    computer = npc_guess()
    complete(computer, player)

def user_guess(): #Users hand in RPSLS
    player = input("Choose 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'Spock': ")
    game = True
    while game:
        if player == 'rock' or player == 'paper' or player == 'scissors'\
        or player == 'lizard' or player == 'Spock':
            return player
    else:
        print("That Choice isn't valid.")

def npc_guess(): #computers hand in RPSLS
    while True:
        computer = random.randrange(0, 4)
        if computer == 0:
            print("The NPC has chosen rock")
            computer = 'rock'        # Need string assignment for all these. Had boolean evaluation before. Without assignment, computer was never taking on a value of 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard' or 'Spock', and what was returned was the random integer from above
        elif computer == 1:
            print("The NPC has chosen paper")
            computer = 'paper'
        elif computer == 2:
            print("The NPC has chosen scissors")
            computer = 'scissors'
        elif computer == 3:
            print("The NPC has chosen lizard")
            computer = 'lizard'
        elif computer == 4:
            print("The NPC has chosen Spock")
            computer = 'Spock'
        return computer


def complete(player, computer): #determines if the computer beat you, if not you win or tie.
    if (computer == 'rock' and player == 'lizard') or ( computer == 'rock' and player == 'paper')\ # Previously had if computer == ('rock' and player == 'lizard') or ... , which will always boil down to "if computer == True" since bool('rock') is true. Then "if computer == True" always evaluates to False since computer is never a boolean value
        or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'scissors') or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'Spock')\
        or (computer == 'scissors' and player == 'paper') or (computer == 'paper' and player == 'lizard')\
        or (computer == 'lizard' and player == 'paper') or (computer == 'lizard' and player == 'Spock')\
        or (computer == 'Spock' and player == 'rock') or (computer == 'Spock' and player == 'scissors'):
            print("The Computer wins")
    elif computer == player:
        print("It was a tie")
    else:
        print("You win!")

main()
```

Comment: This is more of a code review than a StackOverflow answer. You've also left several questionable parts of the original code. I don't think there can be a good answer to this because this is not a question.

Comment: While the question may not be framed in the best manner, the OP states a specific problem that he/she is having (i.e. User always wins) and posts the code needed to investigate the issue. I have proposed a solution to the original issue with an explanation of why the user was winning every time. I left several questionable parts of the code because, while they may be in poor coding style, they are not necessarily incorrect, and do not appear to have anything to do with the original issue reported by OP.

Comment: I don't think this helps StackOverflow. I think this helps this particular OP, at this particular moment in time, maybe. Then no one ever again. This is not how StackOverflow is supposed to work. When I come across these questions, I downvote and vote to close. When they get answered, it is less likely they will go away and more likely that more like it will occur in the future. You may disagree. I may even be in the minority. I stand by my votes.